# Updating date from SimpleDateFormat Android?

Tags: android, string, textview, simpledateformat

I've used `SimpleDateFormat` in my Android app. Like this:

```
final TextView date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);

long datesdf = System.currentTimeMillis();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy");
String dateString = sdf.format(datesdf);
date.setText(dateString);
date.setTextSize(17);
```

By which I get output example:
**01 May, 2015**

But the problem is the date, month or year doesn't get updated, what's wrong with it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean not updated?

Comment: do you mean, it doesn't set on your TextView? If so, try putting the log right below setText or check if your dateString has the desired value.

Comment: If today is 1st of May, then tomorrow it should change to 2nd of May, right? But it's not getting changed! Got it?

Comment: Did you change phone date to 2nd May

Comment: But yesterday I made the app but it should change it's date today, but it's not changed...

Comment: But today is 1st may and showing correctly.

Comment: @AjinkyaMore for checking that....I suggest you to also add HH:mm:ss in the format so that it will be easy for you to check

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually update the date when required. Per your code, `datesdf` holds the *current* time from when the code is run. This (and the date string you build from it etc.) doesn't change/update by itself.

If you just want to detect when a new day starts you could use AlarmManager and schedule an alarm for midnight. However, this should only be required when your app is in use. For example, you can update the date once when the app/Activity is started and schedule an alarm then. When the Activity is paused you don't need the alarm anymore and can cancel it.

Comment: Dude. This must be a comment!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    String formattedDate = date.format(c.getTime());
    SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
    String formattedTime = time.format(c.getTime());
```

use this code for updating date and time also

Comment: It's showing `c` cannot be resolved? Any solution? I'll accept your answer, just tell me this...

Comment: Buddy c is **Calender** instance.

Comment: Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

Answer (score -2):

Guys I found my solution on my own and it's working like charm. Here's the solution:

```
final TextView date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);

final Handler date_handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
        date_handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                date.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy", Locale.US)
                        .format(new Date()));
                date_handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }, 10);
```

It updates the date, month and year automatically and it works 100%!